# Mobile scroll issue in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4, jquery

I used flexslider for product image gallery

Issue: mobile scroll is not working over the image  but scroll is working in empty space or below the image

below code is sample html

```
<div class="flexslider productMain lftInner" id="productMain">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <li><div><img class="productView" src="images/necklace.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/necklace.jpg" alt=""/></div></li>
                        <li><div><img class="productView" src="images/product-img-1.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/product-img-1.jpg" alt=""/></div></li>
                        <li><div><img class="productView" src="images/product-img-1.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/product-img-1.jpg" alt=""/></div></li>
                        <li><div><img class="productView" src="images/product-img-1.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/product-img-1.jpg" alt=""/></div></li>
                        <li><div><img class="productView" src="images/product-img-1.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/product-img-1.jpg" alt=""/></div></li>
                        <li><div><img class="productView" src="images/product-img-1.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/product-img-1.jpg" alt=""/></div></li>
                    </ul>
                    <i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>
                </div>
```

Comment: Are there any javascript issue?

Comment: no error in javascript

Comment: Have you try in other browsers?
Could we see it?
Any other element could be conflict with it?

Comment: @ntzz i check safari and chrome

Comment: Could show us the example online? Have you try to move to other place or remove the image to know which is making the conflict?

Comment: no online link now its in development

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25964/discussion-between-deeban-babu-and-ntzz).

Comment: mobile touch scroll is not working

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this in the past. I overcame it by adding the following parameter to the flexslider function call.

```
useCSS: false
```

Original source for this came from https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/345